# r Copy values from a cell above the missing value

Tags: r, replace, missing-data

I have a large dataset and the shorter version of that is as below

```
 Col1         Col2
 0            1
 1            0.9971
 4            NA
 6            NA
 7            NA
 14           NA
 18           0.9951
 22           NA
 25           NA
 46           0.9941
 57           NA
 59           NA
 60           0.9921
```

For those missing values in Col2, I want the NAs replaced with the value above it from the same column Col2. The final dataset would look like this below.

```
    Col1         Col2
 0            1
 1            0.9971
 4            0.9971
 6            0.9971
 7            0.9971
 14           0.9971
 18           0.9951
 22           0.9951
 25           0.9951
 46           0.9941
 57           0.9941
 59           0.9941
 60           0.9921
```

Comment: If you're open to using the `tidyverse`, you can do `df %>% arrange(Col1) %>% fill(Col2)`, which will do a downward fill.

Comment: @brittenb, that worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a function `na.locf` (NA last observation carried forward) to do this in the package `zoo`:

```
> zoo::na.locf(df)
   Col1   Col2
1     0 1.0000
2     1 0.9971
3     4 0.9971
4     6 0.9971
5     7 0.9971
6    14 0.9971
7    18 0.9951
8    22 0.9951
9    25 0.9951
10   46 0.9941
11   57 0.9941
12   59 0.9941
13   60 0.9921
```

Comment: @Cbraun. that was fantastic.